# want to set frame at run time

Tags: ios, iphone, frame

I am trying to set frame at run time but it has no effects, I am using the following code:

```
int heightt=[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height;

int weidtht=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;


NSLog(@"weidth :%d   height :%d  ",weidtht,heightt);


if (weidtht==375 && heightt==667) {
    heightt=heightt*0.40;
    weidtht=weidtht*0.80;
} else {
    heightt=heightt*0.58;
    weidtht=weidtht*0.190;
}


NSLog(@"weidth :%d   height :%d  ",weidtht,heightt);
[self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(weidtht, heightt, 198, 30)];
```

Comment: Where is this code being run and what is being logged?

Comment: What is the output of bottom NSLog? Do you have autolayout turned off?

Comment: check  autolayout  option , and u can set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES,

Comment: yes i know why this happen. you have to call layoutIfNeeded after your frame changed.

Comment: if you using autolayout : [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

OtherWise : [cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];'

Comment: i m running this code in view didload actually i want to set myView position according to the device screen pixel size using screen resolution percentage bcz my layout working fine for 4s but in iphone 6 and 6 plus it is coming at the top left corner and right and bottom part is dark (unused)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put weidht and height in the fields of x and y?

However try this:

```
CGRect frame = self.myView.frame
frame.size.origin.x = weidtht;
frame.size.origin.y = heightt;
self.myView.frame = frame;
```